# PHP flat file management class

Tags: php, class, file-management, flat

Does anyone know of a class for managing flat file, in PHP? I am making an app that uses them, and I want to know if there is already one that I can use, without making my own.

Comment: Flat file what? Does it have to accomplish anything besides reading and writing a file?

Comment: Editing data without regex or `str_replace`, blocks of data, making and deleting data ... Just a class to make that stuff easier. And it doesn't have to be a class, but OOP with this kinda stuff is good practice.

Comment: What is your use case?  Take it from someone that managed a flat-file based commercial application for five years -- you *do not want to do this*.  With flat files, you have to manage locking, concurrency, indexing, searching, filesystem errors, etc.

Comment: Nothing major, color management, as settings. They would be set in an admin panel, and then stored in a flat file. I think SQL would be overkill.

Comment: So it's mainly configuration data?

Comment: Yes, but not much at all. This data will be accessed for use in CSS, for background colors and stuff like that, on a couple of things on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a good look at [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html) and [Zend_Config_Writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html), components in the Zend Framework.  They stand pretty much alone, so you don't need to import too many other parts of ZF outside of the loader and exception bits.

They allow you to read and write configuration data in an exported PHP array, as an INI file, as JSON, as XML or as YAML.  They *aren't* super light weight, but they are useful, comprehensive, and more importantly, well-written and well-tested.

Comment: Zend (the company) has done a horrible job of differentiating their products (like the absolutely horrid "Zend Server") from both each other and the Zend Framework, which is *sponsored* by them, but run by an independent community.  You don't need to have any Zend product or service installed, you just need to grab the specific parts of the Framework code as needed.  ZF is BSD-licensed, so you can bundle the parts you need with your application, if you're building something for distributon.

Comment: So all I would need to do is download them, include them somewhere, and use them?

Comment: The same as with any other set of PHP classes, yes.

Comment: After looking into it, apparently I would need to have Zend installed. Sorry, I don't know a lot, but I haven't worked with a framework for a long time, and even then it was CodeIgniter.

Comment: All you need is [the zip file](http://framework.zend.com/download/current/) -- scroll down to "Full" or "Minimal".  You need nothing else other than the files in the "library" directory in the zip (and even then just only 2-3 of those are strictly needed *just* to use the Config classes).

Comment: Thanks! I had to register before downloading.... They really want to know where you live, just in case you switch frameworks :)

Comment: Did I? It looks like what you described.

Comment: The last few links do not require registration, that's all.

Comment: Well, I got A minimal download. It included the class I was looking for, anyway though. Plus, a lot of other things I might use someday... :)